# std::string in a multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, stl

Given that:

1) The C++03 standard does not address the existence of threads in any way

2) The C++03 standard leaves it up to implementations to decide whether `std::string` should use Copy-on-Write semantics in its copy-constructor

3) Copy-on-Write semantics often lead to unpredictable behavior in a multi-threaded program

I come to the following, seemingly controversial, conclusion:

**You simply cannot safely and portably use std::string in a multi-threaded program**

Obviously, no STL data structure is thread-safe.  But at least, with std::vector for example, you can simply use mutexes to protect access to the vector.  With an std::string implementation that uses COW, you can't even reliably do that without editing the reference counting semantics deep within the vendor implementation.

Real-world example:

In my company, we have a multi-threaded application which has been thoroughly unit-tested and run through Valgrind countless times.  The application ran for months with no problems whatsoever.  One day, I recompile the application on another version of gcc, and all of a sudden I get random segfaults all the time.  Valgrind is now reporting invalid memory accesses deep within libstdc++, in the std::string copy constructor.

So what is the solution?  Well, of course, I could typedef `std::vector<char>` as a string class - but really, that sucks.  I could also wait for C++0x, which I pray will require implementors to forgo COW.  Or, (shudder), I could use a custom string class.  I personally always rail against developers who implement their own classes when a preexisting library will do fine, but honestly, I need a string class which I can be sure is not using COW semantics; and std::string simply doesn't guarantee that.

Am I right that `std::string` simply cannot be used reliably *at all* in portable, multi-threaded programs?  And what is a good workaround?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594803/is-stdstring-thead-safe-with-gcc-4-3

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know COW string implementation are still out there.

Comment: If your STL implementation uses non thread-safe COW you should replace it with a better one. This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @sbi, not only out there, but quite common.  GCC 4.3.2, (from August 2008) uses COW.

Comment: What is so bad about `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: @jalf, `std::vector<char>` is not that bad, actually, especially with the boost string library functions.  The only downside is the lack of nice syntactic sugar, like the concatenation/append operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that the standard doesn't say a word about memory models and is completely thread unaware, I'd say you can't definitely assume every implementation will be non-cow so no, you can't

Apart from that, if you know your tools, most of the implementations will use non-cow strings to allow multi-threading.

Comment: "most of the implementations will use non-cow strings to allow multi-threading." Not quite true, in fact **most** C++ compilers implement COW strings: gcc, intel, HP... MSVC does not. Most of implementations (with exception of MSVC6) are thread safe because are using atomic counters.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot safely and portably do anything in a multi-threaded program. There is no such thing as a portable multi-threaded C++ program, precisely because threads throw everything C++ says about order of operations, and the results of modifying any variable, out the window.

There's also nothing in the standard to guarantee that `vector` can be used in the way you say. It would be legal to provide a C++ implementation with a threading extension in which, say, any use of a vector outside the thread in which it was initialized results in undefined behavior. The instant you start a second thread, you aren't using standard C++ any more, and you must look to your compiler vendor for what is safe and what is not.

If your vendor provides a threading extension, and also provides a std::string with COW that (therefore) cannot be made thread-safe, then I think for the time being your argument is with your vendor, or with the threading extension, not with the C++ standard. For example, arguably POSIX should have barred COW strings in programs which use pthreads.

You could possibly make it safe by having a single mutex, which you take while doing any string mutation whatsoever, and any reads of a string that's the result of a copy. But you'd probably get crippling contention on that mutex.

Answer (score 8):

You are right. This will be fixed in C++0x. For now you have to rely on your implementation's documentation. For example, recent libstdc++ Versions (GCC) lets you use string objects *as if*
no string object shares its buffer with another one. C++0x forces a library implemetation to protect the user from "hidden sharing".

Answer (score 4):

You can use STLport. It provides non-COW strings. And it has the same behavior on different platforms.

This [article](http://complement.sourceforge.net/compare.pdf) presents comparison of STL strings with copy-on-write and noncopy-
on-write argorithms, based on STLport strings, ropes and GNU libstdc++
implementations.

In a company where I work I have some experience running the same server application built with STLport and without STLport on HP-UX 11.31. The application was compiled with gcc 4.3.1 with optimization level O2. So when I run the progrma built with STLport it processes requests 25% faster comparing to the the same program built without STLport (which uses gcc own STL library).

I profiled both versions and found out that the version without STLport spends much more time in `pthread_mutex_unlock()` (2.5%) comparing to the version with STLport (1%). And `pthread_mutex_unlock()` itself in the version without STLport is called from one of std::string functions.

However, when after profiling I changed assignments to strings in most often called functions in this way:

```
string_var = string_var.c_str(); // added .c_str()
```

there was significant improvement in performance of the version without STLport.

Answer (score 4):

A more correct way to look at it would be "You cannot safely and portably use C++ in a multithreaded environment". There is no guarantee that other data structures will behave sensibly either. Or that the runtime won't blow up your computer. The standard doesn't guarantee *anything* about threads.

So to do **anything** with threads in C++, you have to rely on implementation-defined guarantees. And Then you can safely use `std::string` because each implementation tells you whether or not it is safe to use in a threaded environment.

You lost all hope of true portability the moment you spawned a second thread. `std::string` isn't "less portable" than the rest of the language/library.

Comment: You're right, of course.  If we're talking about what's guaranteed by the standard, no multi-threaded C++ program is portable.  However, the *de facto* state of things is that you can write multi-threaded code that will behave consistently across most modern platforms using things like pthreads or boost threads - with the notable exception of code that uses `std::string`, due to the non-negligible possibility of COW semantics.  Or to put it another way: multi-threaded code that uses `std::vector` is not likely to break *anywhere* these days; but the same cannot be said for `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC, std::string is no longer reference counted shared pointer to a container. They choose to the entire contents by-value in every copy constructor and assignment operator, to avoid multithreading problems.

Answer (score 0):

I regulate the string access:

- make `std::string` members private
- return `const std::string&` for getters
- setters modify the member

This has always worked fine for me and is correct data hiding.

Comment: Does returning a const reference guarantee correct behaviour?  I previously thought so, but I got caught out by some nasty concurrency problems recently, eg: 

    const std::string& MyClass::GetString() const {
      MutexLock lock(m_Mutex);
      return m_MyString;
    }

in this instance, doesn't the mutex get unlocked *before* the return value's copy constructor?  In which case you're liable to get race conditions.

Comment: @the_mandrill: "doesn't the mutex get unlocked before the return value's copy constructor" Of course it gets unlocked before that. All you protect is the creation of a reference. Return by copy in this scenario.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. It has nothing to do with encapsulation; the problem is much deeper. The fact is, a multi-threaded program can't *ever* modify an `std::string` that has been copied, and expect to work properly with all standard-compliant compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable COW semantics, you could force your strings to make copies:

```
// instead of:
string newString = oldString;

// do this:
string newString = oldString.c_str();
```

As pointed out, especially if you could have embedded nulls, then you should use the iterator ctor:

```
string newString(oldString.begin(), oldString.end());
```

Comment: It seems easier and better (especially for code quality) just to use another implementation.

Comment: The above code calls `strlen()` to figure the already known length. Better `string newString(oldString.begin(), oldString.end())`.

Comment: @Bill: this also breaks if the string contained any embedded null characters (which is perfectly legal for `std::basic_string<>` derivatives)

Comment: @sehe: I was lazy and just left Maxim's improvement in the comments.  I've added it into the answer now, thanks!