# Any Disadvantage to using String (C++)

Tags: c++, string, stl

I actually checked on google for this but I usually found the reverse.
Is there actual any disadvantage in C++ to using the string library strings instead of C strings or some kind of character arrays? besides maybe being a bit slower?

Feel free to point me to a dupe, however I've searched and couldn't find anything (altho im sure someone has asked)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's really no significant disadvantage, assuming the vendor implementation of `std::string` is competent.  The `std::string` class is not likely to be any slower than plain C-strings with compiler optimizations turned on.

Even if you find yourself in a situation where you *need* a C string (like say, you need to work with an API that takes a `const char*`), you always have `std::string::c_str()`.

One *possible* disadvantage you might run into is vendor implementations that implement [COW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) semantics in a non-thread-safe manner.  (See [std::string in a multi-threaded program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661154/c-stdstring-in-a-multi-threaded-program))

However, this will be a non-issue in C++0x, and even in C++03 it's really an example of a problematic vendor implementation rather than anything inherently wrong with `std::string`.

Another *possible* disadvantage is the fact that there is some debate as to whether the wording in the C++03 standard requires an `std::string` implementation to use a contiguous memory buffer.  This makes it somewhat questionable whether or not you can do things like read directly from a file into an `std::string` object.  However, it's easy to argue that the C++03 standard *does*, in fact, implicitly require a contiguous buffer, and anyway it's mostly an academic matter because in practice 1) most (or all) implementations of `std::string` in fact do provide a contiguous buffer, and 2) the problem is moot for C++0x, which explicitly requires a contiguous buffer.

Comment: Whether std::string is faster depends on the implementation. Non-COW implementation allocates memory and copies data when passing std::string by value, whereas a COW implementation (GNU std::string) just increments the reference counter.

Answer (score 3):

The only possible case I can think of is when you need to handle really huge strings (say, some mega/gigabytes).  In that case, you need to do quite a few tricks to avoid copying and to implement placement new if STL string class is chosen.  The char arrays will be much straightforward for manipulations like that.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Sorry, I completely mis-understood your question. As for disadvantages, I believe some implementations of the `string` class use reference counting, which can lead to unexpected performance characteristics when it comes to multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO The answer depends on what you're doing.  If you rely on outside libraries that use C Strings, by all means use C Strings.

Or... Maybe you have a complete C String library you've used for years...

Otherwise I'd use the stdlib strings.