# How to delete char * in c++?

Tags: c++

In my application, I create a `char*` like this:

```
class sample
{
    public:
        char *thread;
};

sample::sample()
{
    thread = new char[10];
}

sample::~sample()
{
    delete []thread;
}
```

Am I doing the right thing in the code?

Comment: why `[]thread` and not `delete thread;` only?

Comment: Do you mean `thread = new char[10]`?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper Because he wants to delete the data that is "pointed" to by thread.  The * before thread means its a pointer.  The pointer thread will be "deleted" when it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

List of points to be noted:

1) You need to allocate room for n characters, where n is the number of characters in the string, plus the room for the trailing null byte.

2) You then changed the thread to point to a different string. So you have to use `delete[]` function for the variable you are created using `new[]`.

But why are you fooling around with `new` and `delete` for character data? Why not just use `std::string`, instead of 'C' functions? It's amazing why so many don't do the easiest thing:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int countWords(const char *p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string pString = "The Quick Brown Fox!";

    int numWords1 = countWords(pString.c_str());
    printf("\n\n%d words are in the string %s", numWords1, pString.c_str());

    int numWords2 = countWords(argv[1]);
    printf("\n%d words are in the string %s", numWords2, argv[1]);
}
```

No need for `new[]`, `delete[]`, `strcpy()`, etc.

Use `strlen()`. Better yet, don't use `char*` and use `std::string` for string data.

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` with `std::string`. Use the `.size()` member function - this will work correctly even if the string has embedded null characters. As an added bonus, it's O(1)!

Comment: but isn't std::string generally not thread safe "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661154/c-stdstring-in-a-multi-threaded-program" so it depends on his requirement to use char* or std::string.

Comment: @user258367: No. The very worst case is that you'd have to suppress COW in multi-threaded code by copying a `std::string` via `const char* string::c_str()` and `string::string(const char*, size_t)` to eliminate the COW. Still a whole lot safer than 100% manual string handling.

Answer (score 27):

If you have `[]` after your `new`, you need `[]` after your `delete`. Your code looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's "right"*, but it's very wrong.

You should not use `new[]`, but instead use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`. Even if you weren't doing that, you need to respect the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), or your class is broken.

*Assuming you meant `new char[10]`. Also, more orthodox is `delete[] thread`.