# Is gcc's std::string COW thread-safe?

Tags: string, gcc, stl, clang, copy-on-write

I tested with gcc and confirmed that gcc's std::string implemented COW:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string a(50, 'c');
  std::string b = a;

  *const_cast<char*>(a.c_str()) = 'A';
  std::cout << "a: " << a << "\nb: " << b << std::endl;
}
```

It prints:

```
a: Accccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
b: Accccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

b changed with a. The test result it different if I use clang or VC. So I wish to know if gcc's string COW is thread-safe? Is it ok to use std::string in a multi-thread environment?

Comment: What GCC version is this? I can't reproduce with the latest version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98b24895219ca28b.

Comment: Also, there are *lots* of dups. If you don't want to upgrade your c++ library, you could profitably read some of SO's collective wisdom by searching for threadsafe and std::string.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661154/stdstring-in-a-multi-threaded-program