# std::string messed up when using it as storage within (boost.)async_read_some

Tags: c++, boost-asio, netcat

I am using async_read_some to read data from a port that is saved in a char[] called _data. Its buffer size is big enough for every request:

```
void start() {

    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_,BUFFERSIZE),make_custom_alloc_handler(allocator_,boost::bind(&attentionSession::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));

}

void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred) {

    string ip = socket_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
    log->processData(data_,ip,"memory");
    strcpy(data_,"");

}
```

processData adds some additional information (like timestamp etc.) to the request by copying it to another newly alloced char*. Then this char[] is sent to writeToMemory(char*) to append that char* to the std::string memoryBuffer:

```
void writeCacheToFile() {

    // This function writes buffer data to the log file

    char* temp = new char[memoryBuffer.length() + 1];
    strcpy(temp, memoryBuffer.c_str());
    writeToFile(temp);
    delete[] temp;
    memoryBuffer.clear();

}

void writeToMemory(char* data) {

    int maxSize = 1024;

     // Checks if char* data would 'fit' into the pre-defined maxSize

    if ((strlen((const char*)data) + memoryBuffer.length()) >= maxSize) {
        writeCacheToFile(); // If not the cache memoryBuffer is saved first
    }

    memoryBuffer.append((const char*) data);

    cout << memoryBuffer.length() << endl;

}
```

It works but if there are constantly requests (bombarding it with requests) things get messed up. As you can see above in the writeToMemory() function I'll added a line to print out the current length of memoryBuffer and this is where I think it has somethings to do with thread safety of std::strings:

```
96
188
284
3639
94
190
286
2591
102
198
294
388
484
2591
96
2591
96
190
286
2591
```

The length of each (processed by processData()) request is 96 characters. But here the length of memoryBuffer just rises and falls down - some lengths are even bigger than maxSize (1024 chars).

**EDIT:** Sam pointed out I should add some more code. This is how I start the io_service:

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
boost::scoped_ptr<boost::thread> ioServiceThread; 
server_class server (ioService,PORT); // Create server instance
ioServiceThread.reset (new boost::thread ( boost::bind ( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService  ) ) ); 
// Only one threaded io_service (to receive user inputs in main() function)
```

And this is the async_acceptor's function after completing a request:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<session_class> session_ptr;

void handleAccept(session_ptr thisSession, const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {
      thisSession->start(); // Calls the start() function above
      thisSession.reset(new session(ioService,LOGGING_CLASS));
      acceptor.async_accept(thisSession->socket(),boost::bind(&server_class::handleAccept, this, thisSession, PLACEHOLDER_ERROR));
    }
 }
```

The session_class holds the functions start() and handle_read(x,y) mentioned above. LOGGING_CLASS provides the class to write log files (holds the functions writeCacheToFile() and writeToMemory(char*)). log (mentioned above) is a kind of this class.

**EOE: END OF EDIT**

If I try to fix outsource the caching part (appending received char* to std::string) with boost::threads it ends up with a totally mixed up memoryBuffer

Is it really the thread safety of std::strings or something else I missed?

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Paul

Comment: What makes you think a std::string is thread safe?

Comment: This topic is also here on StackOverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594803/is-stdstring-thead-safe-with-gcc-4-3) but I don't know whether g++ 4.2.1 supports thread safe std::strings.

Comment: The current standard does not mention threads, so a std::string is not thread safe. What are you trying to do with multiple threads anyhow?

Comment: To outsource those copying processes of the char* to the string memoryBuffer. This failed. But async_read_some is also some kind of threading or am I wrong?

Comment: The async_read_some method is not some kind of threading. The completion handlers can be invoked by multiple threads if you have a pool of them invoking io_service::run(). How are you invoking io_service::run() or io_service::poll()?

Comment: @Paul you didn't answer my question. Do you have a single thread invoking run(), or multiple threads?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just read the last sentence as a question. I am invoking run() as a single thread `new boost::thread( boost::bind ( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService) )`. I am not using a thread pool or something else just this one thread.

Comment: How do you invoke additional async_read_some operations on the socket after the first one?

Comment: I am reusing handle_read: `socket_.async_read_some(BUFFER,make_custom_alloc_handler(allocator_,boost::bind(&handle_read, shared_from_this(), PLACEHOLDER_ERROR, PLACEHOLDER_TRANSFBYTES)));`

Comment: @Paul you might want to update your question with a more complete example then. It was non-obvious to me and could be the source of your problem. Typically async operations are chained together, ex: start another `async_read_some` in the completion handler of the previous operation.

Comment: Done. Hopefully it helps understanding what I am doing. Async code just makes it more complicated. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem wasn't Boost nor Boost::Asio. It was the method how I tested my application:

I used nc (Netcat) to test the performance and functions of my application with this command

```
nc localhost 4450 <testfile
```

where testfile contained a 36 characters long test string. Netcat wasn't only slow - it was the **origin** of this problem.

After I changed my strategy and coded a little boost::asio application to send the same requests to my application it worked. Fast, easy and without any problems.

I learned my lesson: Never use Netcat for stress tests again!

Comment: just curious, what was the problem with netcat? It's a tremendously useful program in my experience.

Comment: Netcat messed up the transferred string. It somehow got mixed with other stuff even though I am not using port 4450 normally. Really weird. But it works without any problem with this small self-scripted application.

Answer (score 2):

I made this same point as a comment but I figured it would be worth expanding into an answer. Posting the snippets of code you have are not terribly helpful, they don't give us the full picture. For example, the following concepts are not clear to me:

1. You're not checking the `bytes_transferred` parameter in your `async_read_some` handler. This is *very important* because even though you tell it to read `n` bytes it [can](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) return when reading `n - x` bytes where `x <= n`. As the [documentation states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html), you should consider using one of the composed operations like the `async_read` [free function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html).
2. you're using [custom memory allocations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/allocation.html) for your asynchronous read operations, presumably based on the [example provided](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp). Why do you need that?
3. buffer lifetime. Ex: do your buffers stay in scope until the `async_read` handler is invoked?
4. object lifetime. Ex: are you using `shared_ptr` properly? Is the `io_service` in scope for the entirety of its event loop?
5. are you using a single `io_service` per process or one per thread?
6. why you need threads? Typically it's easier to understand asynchronous programming in a single threaded context first.

All of these are very important concepts to get right when using Boost.Asio. Part of debugging is boiling down a perceived problem into a smaller reproducer. This is useful both on Stack Overflow and for becomming a good programmer in general. It will help you understand the problem, and also help **us** help you find it. I strongly suggest you spend some effort on making a smaller reproducible example that we can compile. If that's not possible, consider using multiple threads only after you have proved a single threaded scenario works.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. I check point 1 and adapted this to my code - good point. Point 2: If I wouldn't do this my application eats up all memory straight. 3: Best point. I didn't think about this one (thought this would be safe but I was wrong). 4: Everything is in the main function(); so it should be no problem. 5. One in the main() function; no threading. 6. Unfortunately I failed in phrasing my idea of threading the logging part. Thanks for your help; helped me a lot to fix my code but I solved the main problem differently.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is refactor the line where you invoke async_read_some.  It is so long it is almost impossible to see what is happening.

My guess would be that when you hammer this, you will have new calls to handle_read before the old calls return.  handle_read is not thread-safe.  Apart from anything else,

```
strcpy(data_,"");
```

is going to give you trouble when multiple copies are all trying to copy into data_.

You need to make handle_read thread-safe.

Comment: It works better but not perfect. There are still some 'lengths' that break ranks.

Comment: They are much bigger than maxSize (1024 chars). Some even exceed it 2 or 3 times.