# why does this openmp give SIGSEGV?

Tags: c++, openmp

The code works fine without using openmp. I have used private and shared but still it gives SIGSEGV on the line where my struct `SinRes` is defined.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(row, dt1, dt1s, dtmp, dat1, atur) shared(turVec)
for(row=0; row<ndicts; ++row)
{ 
     dt1 = kI(keys)[row]; 
     dt1s = to_string(dj(dt1));
     dtmp = dt1s.substr(0, 4) + "." + dt1s.substr(4, 2) + "." + dt1s.substr(6, 2);
     dat1 = kK(data)[row];
     dat1s = kK(dat1->k)[1];
     atur =  breakLogic(dat1s, mpar, dtmp);
     ///free(atur);
     turVec.push_back(atur);
 }
```

The error message is

```
(gdb) run 5 x5.csv
Starting program: /root/cwork/ompTur 5 x5.csv
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at    0x2aaaaaacd000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x2aaaac2e1700 (LWP 17500)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaac4e2700 (LWP 17501)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaac6e3700 (LWP 17502)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaad1e9700 (LWP 17503)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaad3ea700 (LWP 17504)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaad5eb700 (LWP 17505)]
[New Thread 0x2aaaad7ec700 (LWP 17506)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x2aaaad7ec700 (LWP 17506)]
0x0000000000407a7a in sinRes::sinRes (this=0x2aaab401f430) at ompTur.cpp:33
33      struct sinRes {
(gdb)
```

I am new to openmp. Do I need to use any of the other constructs like `critical`?

The code for SinRes is simply

```
struct sinRes {
    double pnl, numTrds, firstVar;
    string dt;
};
```

Comment: It looks like you're smashing the stack.

Comment: you mean overloading it? i have set it to unlimited and am monitoring memory usage by top. It seems to be just ~500mb.

Comment: What I mean is that some code somewhere write outside the bounds of some local variables, and therefore altering the stack in places that should not be altered.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on how to check and fix that?

Comment: Stack-smashing can be very hard to find, especially in multithreaded applications. You need to check arr writes to arrays and local variables, and check array indexes to make sure that none are outside of the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are declaring variables of type `std::string` as `omp private` and `omp shared`. It probably will not work because `std::string` uses dynamic mem allocations, and is not thread-safe.

[Is std::string thead-safe with gcc 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594803/is-stdstring-thead-safe-with-gcc-4-3/5305437#5305437)

You probably need to manually define thread-local std::string in the for loop, and avoid using  `std::string::push_back()` because it involve a race condition.

Comment: It was the push_back which was causing race conditions. changed it to turVec[itr] = atr and it worked.

Comment: Declaring a variable as `private` creates an **uninitialised** thread-local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ container classes are not thread-safe with respect to write operations. One has to use explicitly synchronised accesses, e.g.:

```
#pragma omp critical
turVec.push_back(atur);
```

`operator[]` does not extend the internal storage of the vector object when necessary and therefore allows for concurrent access.